# How can I write a Lambda function in node.js that returns binary data?

Tags: node.js, lambda

I want to write a Lambda function in node.js that returns binary data. I'd like for the response header to be "application/octet-stream", but it isn't absolutely necessary.

It appears to be the case that the response header is always "application/json" and there isn't any way to change it.

The documentation for the callback function says:
"The callback function takes two arguments: an Error and a response. The response object must be compatible with JSON.stringify."

I don't want anybody to "stringify" my data or convert it to JSON. I just want to return a buffer of bytes exactly as-is.

Comment: By Lambda function do you mean aws lambda? Who is calling it? Are you using api gateway?

Comment: Yes, it is an AWS Lambda function, and yes, we are using API Gatway. The client is an iOS application.

Comment: And what kind of binary data are you wanting to return?

Comment: An octet-stream (i.e. a stream of bytes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you have two options, return a base64 encoded string or do a redirect to S3 which contains your binary blob.

Your response is always a JSON object but you can specify the content-type and you can use base64 to encoding to send binary data through API Gateway.

## Base64 Encoding

Without knowing much about your code consider this example:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const result = Buffer.from('Hello World!', 'utf8')
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
      },
      body: result.toString('base64'), // SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
      isBase64Encoded: true
    }
}
```

You're returning an object but specifying the body is a base64 encoded string which API Gateway should transform into an octet-stream.

You may need to configure API Gateway to allow `*/*` media types. [Here is an article with more details](https://medium.com/@ngchiwang/aws-api-gateway-lambda-return-binary-image-ba8faa660839).

## S3 Redirect

The other option, which would make more sense for large binary objects, would be to write your binary objects into S3 as files and then return a `statusCode: 302` with a redirect url to [a signed S3 url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property).

Something like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    return {
      statusCode: 302,
      headers: {
        'Location': 'http://example.com/example.png'
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. We decided to use the base64 approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just spent the last few days figuring this out. If your goal is to use API Gateway with a lambda integration to return a binary file (in my case from S3), first thing to note is don't bother trying to do it without the lambda proxy integration.

I spent a majority of my time on that trying to write a mapping template that would take the JSON output of my lambda and return an integration response body of just the Base64 encoded string.  It doesn't work and mapping templates don't support going from JSON to binary for the integration response.  Don't waste your time.

When you enable lambda proxy on the integration request, AWS will take care of converting the JSON response body of the lambda to the proper method response.  It will do this using only a few parameters:

1. Accept header sent from the client
2. Content-Type returned from the method response
3. Binary Media Types list

For everything to work as expected, the first option in the Accept header sent from the client must be in the Binary Media Types list.  The Content-Type returned from the lambda must also be in the Binary Media Types list.

Since we are using a lambda proxy integration, we can have a response in our lambda like below.  AWS will take care of converting the body to binary for the requester since we specify the response body isBase64Encoded and the body is a valid base64 string.  It will also map the headers I want to return as well:

```
{
    statusCode: 200,
    body: base64Body,
    isBase64Encoded: true,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': contentType, 
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=${fileName}`
    },
}
```

My eventual goal was to make it so that I could put the URL of my endpoint in an  tag so that users can download files.  There is a caveat with this that took me forever to realize.  When you click on the a tag and it links to the URL we have set up for the download, it sends the Accept header as text/html no matter what.  We can't change that without doing anything incredibly hacky.  Therefore, we have to ensure that we add text/html to the Binary Media Types list.  If you use */* instead of text/html, it will try to turn everything into binary including your application/json responses from all other endpoints.

The only other key thing to note to get this to work is to make sure that you are mapping all of your request parameters and response parameters throughout.  Here is an example gateway method that is working for me (this is a cloudformation template yaml):

```
DownloadFileGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      RequestParameters:
        method.request.path.sortId: true
        method.request.path.fileId: true
        method.request.header.Accept: true
        method.request.header.Content-Type: true
      Integration:
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            ResponseParameters:
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,Content-Disposition,Accept,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'GET,OPTIONS'"
              method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              method.response.header.Content-Type: "'integration.response.header.Content-Type'"
              method.response.header.Content-Disposition: "'integration.response.header.Content-Disposition'"
              method.response.header.Accept: "'integration.response.header.Accept'"
        Credentials: !GetAtt ApiGatewayIamRole.Arn
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        ContentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
        RequestParameters:
          integration.request.header.Accept: "method.request.header.Accept"
          integration.request.header.Content-Type: "method.request.header.Content-Type"
        TimeoutInMillis: 29000
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        Uri: !Sub
          - 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${lambdaArn}/invocations'
          - lambdaArn: !GetAtt "DownloadFileV2.Arn"
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: 'Empty'
            image/jpeg: 'Empty'
            image/png: 'Empty'
          ResponseParameters:
            method.response.header.X-Requested-With: false
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: false
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: false
            method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'
            method.response.header.Content-Disposition: true
            method.response.header.Content-Type: true
            method.response.header.Accept: true
          StatusCode: 200
      OperationName: 'Download file'
      ResourceId: !Ref FileIdResource
      RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
```

Finally, this is how I get a file from s3 and convert it to a base64 string in javascript:

```
const s3Params = {
                Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
                Key,
            }
const s3Response = await s3.getObject(s3Params).promise();
const base64Body = Buffer.from(s3Response.Body).toString('base64');
```

Hopefully, this helps save someone from the madness I just went through.  Good luck.